# Calling top-level async function from different Isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Unable to call a top-level async function from another isolate, an example would be trying to access SharedPreferences/Document-path value from a different isolate since getting the instance would require 'awaiting'.

In my case, I am using [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader), downloads in another isolate, as soon as the download completes an encryption method is called which saves the result in a document path, [path_provider's](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` returns a future which requires awaiting. I have made the encrypt function async and it is never getting called using both `compute` and `Isolate.spawn` so that it computes the encryption in another isolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that there are no plugins available in isolates, thus `path_provider` and `shared_preferences` don't work when called from the isolate.

If you need the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` then you can determine that path before you start the isolate and hand it to the isolate as a message. This way you have the path available in the isolate and can save the file there. Accessing shared_prefs is not really possible, you can only do that after the isolate completes.

There are some projects like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate that try to make plugins available in isolates. You can explore those and see if it fits your needs.

Specifically for [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) there is an example in the README that shows how to communicate between the background isolate that handles the download callback and the main isolate of your app.
Basically you need to pass a message to the main isolate like `PleaseGiveMeTheApplicationDocumentsDirectory` and then answer the message with `HereYourGoThisIsTheApplicationDocumentsDirectory`.

You can use `IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName` to get the `SendPort` of the main isolate and pass it the `SendPort` of the background isolate and then answer with the correct path. Once both sides know where to send messages to, you can pass whatever you want, you can also pass a message that triggers some `shared_preferences` usage in the main isolate.